# When does Mathematica automatically use dispatch tables for function evaluation?

Tags: performance-tuning, hashing

I've read the documentation for `Dispatch`, and it says:

> Lists of rules produced by assignments made with = and := are automatically optimized with dispatch tables when appropriate.

I've got a function that has been defined by explicit statements of the form `f[a]:=q`. There are a very large number of these statements, and Mathematica can be very slow to evaluate any particular `f[a]`. I'm wondering if it's worth trying to convert the function assignments to a list of rules and use `Dispatch`, or if Mathematica is likely already using a dispatch table due to the setup.

Comment: A quick check suggests that you should not forget to test `Association` which is made for dictionary-styled data. Please evaluate `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/6IwgG.png"]` to see my small test. Btw, a dispatched table of rules is the slowest possibility there.

Comment: In my experience, even millions of simple defintions didn't significantly slow down function dispatch mechanism. You may see something like a 30% slowdown if you move from say 100000 definitions to say 5000000 definitions. As far as I know, definitions not using patterns, are stored internally in a hash table. Definitions using patterns are stored differently, also using certain optimizations, AFAIK. Those optimizations might not scale as well with the number of definitions. Can you provide a self-contained example with working code? It is hard to tell from your description, what's going on.

Comment: The number of definitions here is less than a million, and do not use patterns. It's a bit tricky to provide a self-contained example since the full list of definitions isn't exactly self-contained, but I'll try to think of one.

Comment: @Matt What is `q` in your real case? Are you sure this slowness comes from evaluation step from `f[a]` to `q` and not from evaluation of `q` itself? Since you use [`:=`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), `q` is evaluated every time you call `f[a]`.

Comment: The `q` are (often long) polynomials in objects of the form `QR[__]`, where QR isn't given any definition and hence is not evaluated. Could the problem just be that the `q` are very long expressions? I don't think there's any other evaluation involved.

Comment: @Matt: "Could the problem just be that the q are very long expressions?" It could, for example, if you're reaching your physical memory limit. As others already said, it's hard to tell without working example. By the way, please [ping users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) when replying to their comments. You don't have to be pinged, since you're author of this post, but others may not be aware of your replies.